# Agile extension tester certification mock tests

Tags: agile-testing, certification, istqb

I am giving ISTQB Agile extension tester certification exam in next 2 days.
I could see single mock test paper roaming around internet.
I would like to solve few more mock papers. Can i get these test papers for free anywhere please?

Note:  This exam is different from ISEB foundation level exam.

Comment: Why negative vote?

Comment: This exam is not ISEB foundation level. This is ISEB agile extension tester...

Comment: I raised as a duplicate as I think the answers in that question are applicable to any level of the test.

Comment: @ECiurleo I am just looking for Yes or No answer for the mock test papers. If yes then where can i find it..
But I didnt find any applicable answer from the tagged duplicated question. My question is purely different & for the other certification